# How to reset TTL when a redis key is accessed?

Tags: python, redis

I have some keys with TTL in redis. So, normally the key will be evicted when the TTL passed.

But what I want to do is, in every access (retrieval) to the key, I will want to reset the TTL to the original value I set earlier.

For example: I have set 2 hours for a key. After 1 hour later, the key is accessed. I want to set the TTL to 2 hours again at that time. So, the key will only be evicted if it's not accessed in its TTL lifetime.

How to do this efficiently?

Comment: Surprised this isn't a default command actually... seems like a common use case!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can only do this by issuing another `EXPIRE` command with the accessing command. Even the [official documentation](https://redis.io/commands/expire#refreshing-expires) does not mention any other option.

You might want to put these commands on a pipeline to have a better response time.

For example:

```
connection = redis.StrictRedis()
with connection.pipeline() as pipe:
    pipe.get("key")
    pipe.expire("key", 7200)
    pipe.execute()
```

Comment: Thanks, I also couldn't find anything better than this one.